# Removing one point does not change fundamental group

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Let $X$ be a path-connected topological space, $x_0\in X$, s.t. $x_0$ has an open neighbourhood homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^d$ for some $d\ge 3$.

The task is to show that $\pi_1(X)\cong \pi(X\setminus\{x_0\})$ (the base point does not matter as all spaces in question are path-connected).

We may use that $X\setminus\{x_0\}$ is path-connected. I have already shown the claim in the case that $\{x_0\}$ is closed, however I haven't been able to proof it without assuming this.

Comment: Do you know Seifert-van Kampen's theorem?

Comment: yes, I have used it in the case that $x_0$ is closed, because then I choose $X-\{x_0\}$ as one of the open subsets for SvK.

Comment: no because manifolds are by definition hausdorff but in my setting $X$ is not assumed to be hausdorff. Indeed, if $X$ was hausdorff, then $x_0$ is closed and I have already found a proof in that case.

Comment: @nilsw where does the argument use that a point is closed?

Comment: @AndresMejia I use that $X - \{ x_0\}$ is open which is an assumption of SvK.

Comment: Oh I see. Take an open ball using the local homeomorphism with R^n and use basically the same argument

Comment: I don’t think it works because I want to take away a closed set. However if I take away a closed ball it is only closed w.r.t. to thesubspace topology of U whichever’s not guarantee being closed w.r.t to the topology of X.